# Update app icons

Tags: feature-request, android-app, user-interface, ios-app, icons

Please **remove the gloss** from the app icons.

UPDATE: Take this, I won't charge for it :)

[image: Bold version]

UPDATE: This one from the subheader above.

[image: Conform version]

Anyway, at this [official logo download page](https://stackoverflow.com/company/logos) it is already updated.

Comment: I'd personally prefer if we got rid of the gloss completely from the icon in all locations, not just from the iOS app. It doesn't even match the rest of the Stack Exchange theme.

Comment: @animuson wow, why the downvotes? Where should I put this? I came from a direct link in the app!

Comment: [Voting is different on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) - *On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.*

Comment: @animuson Updated (-iOS), hope they will roll it out for xmas :D

Comment: I like this. We need to update our Android icon too, since Android is all in on icons wrapped in circles now (again).

Comment: @Cai Edit: Removed drama from wording.